# Power BI If Blank Then Put Value

Tags: powerbi

This snippet displays the chart we are looking at and it has blanks. Instead of blanks for those dates and ID's we want to show what those values are; however, the values(Rates) may not be the same for every ID or Date. (This may happen on rare occasions.)

[image: Visual Display]

This snippet displays the data being pulled into Power BI from excel (Just sample data). Notice that all the dates are in order, but notice that some of the ID's do not have entries for certain dates.

[image: Table Display]

I want to be able to say IF(ID is blank per this date, then put Value(Rate) that is attached to this ID).

This may not be possible to do in Power BI. We have an excel spreadsheet with similar data doing what we want but we wanted to automate by using Power BI.

Any Thoughts?

Update

I have got the measures to work in my favor, however; I need to get the total of the measure: Value Or Rate measure. I do have Value Or Rate - visual totals if I can do the same thing as the Value Or Rate measure with a total that would be great.

Please see the updated screen screenshots below.

[Visual with fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3DdZ.png) 
[Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHKv4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a measure, you could do something like below. I'm assuming that you have a model as follows:

- Fact: (Date, ID, Value)
- DimDate: (Date, ...)
- Rates: (ID, Rate)
- Dim: (ID, ...)

With these tables you'd have relationships as below:

- Dim -1:N-> Fact
- Dim <-1:1-> Rates
- DimDate -1:N-> Fact

With the model above, you could then build a visual of:

- Rows: DimDate[Date]
- Columns: Dim[ID]
- Values: [Value Or Rate Measure]

```
Value = SUM ( 'Fact'[Value] )
```

```
Rate = SUM ( 'Rates'[Rate] )
```

```
Value Or Rate Measure =
VAR Value = [Value]
RETURN
  IF ( ISBLANK ( Value ), [Rate], Value )
```

This might not do what you want for totals - you didn't specify. So if you need visual totals you might try the following:

```
Value or Rate - visual totals =
SUMX (
  CROSSJOIN ( VALUES ( 'Dim'[ID] ), VALUES ( 'DimDate'[Date] ) ),
  [Value Or Rate Measure]
)
```

You could also handle this in Power Query M, assuming you have the same tables I've described above. I'm assuming each table has an associated query of the same name.

```
let
    Source = Table.AddColumn(Dim, "Date", each DimDate[Date]),
    #"Expanded Date" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Source, "Date"),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Date", {"id", "Date"}, Fact, {"ID", "Date"}, "Fact", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Fact" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Fact", {"Value"}, {"Value"}),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Fact", {"id"}, Rates, {"ID"}, "Rates", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Rates" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Rates", {"Rate"}, {"Rate"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Rates", "Value Or Rate", each if [Value] = null then [Rate] else [Value]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Value", "Rate"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Here, we're doing something similar, but at a table level, instead of as a measure. We crossjoin Dim[ID] and DimDate[Date] to get a dense table of all date and ID combinations. Then we left join the original Fact table and the Rates table. Then we add a column that takes [Value] if it exists, or [Rate] if [Value] is null.

Comment: greggyb, 

I gave this a try, but it still gave me a blank outcome, but the totals worked perfectly. That is one step forward in the right direction. 

It seems when you use an if statement: 

Var Value = [value]
IF(ISBLANK(value), [value], value) 

It will just give blanks because the values from both are the same. I am not sure if Power BI just can't do that or if I am just not understanding IF Stamets. 

Thanks,

Comment: It's not `IF ( ISBLANK ( Value ), [Value], Value )`. It's `IF ( ISBLANK ( Value ), [Rate], Value )`. You need to have a measure, [Rate] that returns the rate for a given ID. Please make an edit to your original question, adding the new code you've written, and a screengrab of the model relationships you're using, and samples of the other data tables.

Comment: greggyb, I have updated the post on what the main goal is. Is there a way to get the total sum of the Value or Rate Measure?

Comment: What does your rate measure return if you put it on the visual?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3DdZ.png

If you see the image link above in the post or named: Visual with fields. That is how it is returned. The total measure returns only if the value field has a value and if it does not then it returns a blank. I need it to return a rate if the value field is empty and then total the rates at the bottom of the visual.

Comment: Right I saw that. And I'm curious what your rate measure returns. It's not on the visual as you've posted it. I also see that your relationships don't match what I suggested.

Comment: I found what I was doing wrong and it was in the relationships. This solution fixed the issue. Thank you so much.