# Paginated Report Matrix Fill Value if Blank from another column

Tags: matrix, ssrs-2008, optional-values, powerbi-paginated-reports, nonblank

I have the below matrix in the paginated report, if a cell is blank I want to fill the value from the column "All". Any idea?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMnkG.png)

From the above example for the first row, all blank cells should be filled with a value from "All" column (49).

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57855342/power-bi-if-blank-then-put-value) answer your question? The issue is similar, but read both the question and the answer.

Comment: If the "all" column a total column or does it appear in your dataset as "all"? If you can share some sample data from your dataset that would be useful.